# xsd /c fails on Microsoft_Data_Entity_Design_Edmx_3.xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd.exe

I'm trying to generate c# code from a Microsoft schema, with the help of the xsd tool. Here is the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:cg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration"
           xmlns:gen="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator"
           xmlns:csdl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm"
           xmlns:ssdl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl"
           xmlns:msl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs"
           xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx"
           targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
      Entity Data Model Designer Schema
      Copyright (c) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
    </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>

  <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration" schemaLocation="System.Data.Resources.CodeGenerationSchema.xsd" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl" schemaLocation="System.Data.Resources.SSDLSchema_3.xsd" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" schemaLocation="System.Data.Resources.CSDLSchema_3.xsd" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs" schemaLocation="System.Data.Resources.CSMSL_3.xsd" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" schemaLocation="System.Data.Resources.EntityStoreSchemaGenerator.xsd"/>
  <xs:attribute name="CopyToSSDL" type="xs:boolean" />
  <xs:element name="Edmx" type="edmx:TEdmx" />
  <xs:complexType name="TEdmx">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:group ref="edmx:GDesignerFirstGroup" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:group ref="edmx:GDesignerLastGroup" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:group ref="edmx:GDesignerOnly" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="Version" type="xs:string" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
  <!-- GDesignerFirstGroup and GDesignerLastGroup allow us to define the xsd to be order-independent for the designer element & mutually-exclusive runtime & dataservices elements-->
  <xs:group name="GDesignerFirstGroup">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:group ref="edmx:GDesignerDataGroup" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:group ref="edmx:GRuntimeDataGroup" minOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>
  <xs:group name="GDesignerLastGroup">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:group ref="edmx:GRuntimeDataGroup" minOccurs="1" />
      <xs:group ref="edmx:GDesignerDataGroup" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>
  <xs:group name="GDesignerOnly">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:group ref="edmx:GDesignerDataGroup" minOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>
  <xs:group name="GRuntimeDataGroup">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="Runtime" type="edmx:TRuntime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="DataServices" type="edmx:TDataServices" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:group>
  <xs:group name="GDesignerDataGroup">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Designer" type="edmx:TDesigner" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>
  <xs:complexType name="TDesigner">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Connection" type="edmx:TConnection" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="Options" type="edmx:TOptions" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="Diagrams" type="edmx:TDiagrams" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TOptions">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="DesignerInfoPropertySet" type="edmx:TDesignerInfoPropertySet" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TDiagrams">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Diagram" type="edmx:TDiagram" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TConnection">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="DesignerInfoPropertySet" type="edmx:TDesignerInfoPropertySet" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TDesignerInfoPropertySet">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="DesignerProperty" type="edmx:TDesignerProperty" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TDesignerProperty">
    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="Value" type="xs:string" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TDiagram">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="EntityTypeShape" type="edmx:TEntityTypeShape" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="AssociationConnector" type="edmx:TAssociationConnector" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="InheritanceConnector" type="edmx:TInheritanceConnector" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <!-- workaround for our model test to pass -->
    <!-- TODO, we need to move this new value to a new XSD version -->
    <xs:attribute name="DiagramId" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
    <xs:attribute name="ZoomLevel" type="xs:int" use="optional" />
    <xs:attribute name="ShowGrid" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />
    <xs:attribute name="SnapToGrid" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />
    <xs:attribute name="DisplayType" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TEntityTypeShape">
    <xs:attribute name="EntityType" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="PointX" type="xs:double" use="optional" />
    <xs:attribute name="PointY" type="xs:double" use="optional" />
    <xs:attribute name="Width" type="xs:double" use="optional" />
    <xs:attribute name="Height" type="xs:double" use="optional" />
    <xs:attribute name="IsExpanded" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />
    <xs:attribute name="FillColor" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TAssociationConnector">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ConnectorPoint" type="edmx:TConnectorPoint" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Association" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="ManuallyRouted" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TInheritanceConnector">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ConnectorPoint" type="edmx:TConnectorPoint" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="EntityType" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="ManuallyRouted" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TConnectorPoint">
    <xs:attribute name="PointX" type="xs:double" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="PointY" type="xs:double" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TRuntime">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="StorageModels" type="edmx:TRuntimeStorageModels" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="ConceptualModels" type="edmx:TRuntimeConceptualModels" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="Mappings" type="edmx:TRuntimeMappings" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TRuntimeConceptualModels">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="csdl:Schema" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TRuntimeStorageModels">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="ssdl:Schema" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TRuntimeMappings">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="msl:Mapping" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TDataServices">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="csdl:Schema" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I'm running the tool in the directory that contains the main schema and all related schema as well. It is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Xml\Schemas".

It fails miserably with the following warnings:

```
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.17929]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Schema validation warning: The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm:Schema' element is not declared. Line 162, position 8.
Schema validation warning: The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs:Mapping' element is not declared. Line 157, position 8.
Schema validation warning: The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl:Schema' element is not declared. Line 152, position 8.
Schema validation warning: The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm:Schema' element is not declared. Line 147, position 8.

Warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or may produce incorrect results.

Error: Error generating classes for schema 'Microsoft_Data_Entity_Design_Edmx_3'.
  - The element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl:Schema' is missing.
```

I'm assuming that the schema should be fixed to allow xsd to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the XSD file itself, you'll notice it has external references to other XSD files:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration" schemaLocation="System.Data.Resources.CodeGenerationSchema.xsd" />
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl" schemaLocation="System.Data.Resources.SSDLSchema_3.xsd" />
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" schemaLocation="System.Data.Resources.CSDLSchema_3.xsd" />
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs" schemaLocation="System.Data.Resources.CSMSL_3.xsd" />
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" schemaLocation="System.Data.Resources.EntityStoreSchemaGenerator.xsd"/>
```

Note how they're file names without directory paths.

You need to copy those other files in the same working directory that the XSD.exe tool is reading the `Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Edmx_3.xsd` from.